# Exercise about second-order elliptic equations with parameter alpha. (Evans PDE Book)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following problem which derives from problem 5 in chapter 6 of Evans Book "Partial Different Equations":

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded subset of $R^n$, $\alpha>0, f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and we have:

\begin{cases}  -\Delta u_\alpha= f  \ \textrm{ in }\  \Omega \\ \alpha u_\alpha + \frac{\partial u_\alpha}{\partial \nu}=0 \ \textrm{ on } \ \partial \Omega\end{cases}

(a) Prove that when $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ then $u_\alpha \rightarrow u_D$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ where $u_D$ is a solution of:

(D) \begin{cases}  -\Delta u= f  \ \textrm{ in } \  \Omega \\ u=0 \ \textrm{on} \ \partial \Omega\end{cases}

(b) Prove that when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ then, if $f \perp1$ (which is the same as $\int_\Omega f=0)$ , we have $u_\alpha \rightarrow u_N$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ where $u_N$ is a solution of:

(N) \begin{cases}  -\Delta u= f  \ \textrm{ in } \  \Omega \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0 \ \textrm{ on } \ \partial \Omega\end{cases}.

I manage to solve problem 5 of Evans Book but so far I'm not be able to make progress on this exercise.

Comment: What have you tried? You should at least be able to prove boundedness of $(u_\alpha)$ independent of $\alpha$, and weak convergence. Then strong convergence follows from convergence of norms.

Comment: @daw In (a) I have proven the boundness of $(u_\alpha)$ and in (b) i have proven that the system (N) has a weak solution $u_N$ if and only if we have f perpendicular to 1. Could you explain me more how we get the weak convergence and convergence of norms to get the strong convergence? Sorry for asking so much but I'm a beginner in functional analysis and I'm having a hard time doing exercises this by myself.

Comment: What is $u$ in your boundary condition? Is it $u_\alpha$?

Comment: @mathdoge yes it's $u_\alpha$. Spelling error. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: To pass to the limit, you utilize the boundedness independent of $\alpha$. For (i), if $|u_\alpha|_{H^1}$ is bounded independent of $\alpha$, then it has a weakly convergent subsequence in $H^1$. I am not sure if strong convergence is helpful, but $H^1$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$, so you might extract a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^2$.

Comment: Ok, so we have a strongly convergent subsequence of $u_\alpha$ in $L^2$. But then we also need to see that the derivative of $u_\alpha$ also converges strongly to the derivative of the subsequence in $L^2$ to have that $u_\alpha$ converges strongly in $H^1$. But how do we show this?

Comment: I think we need weak convergence only. Take $v \in H^1$ and consider $(-\Delta u_\alpha, v) = (f,v)$. Do integration by parts to the left, and see how weak convergence helps you pass to the limit. We might need that $\alpha |u_\alpha|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$ is bounded independent of $\alpha$ to extract a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Ok doing integration by parts on the left we get $\int_{\partial \Omega} \alpha u_\alpha v + \int_\Omega \bigtriangledown u_\alpha \bigtriangledown v = \int_\Omega fv$. From this we know that when $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ we need to have $u=0$  on $\partial \Omega$ because the right side is limited ($f \in L^2$ and $v \in H^1(\Omega)$). Can u explain to me why we need weak convergence to pass to the limit? Can´t we use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem since $\alpha |u_\alpha|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$ is bounded independent of $\alpha$. Also sorry for the late response.

Comment: Weak convergence in $H^1$ helps you pass to the limit in $(\nabla u_\alpha, v)$ term. But I am not sure whether Dominated Convergence theorem helps you pass to the limit in the boundary term, because we don't know $\alpha u_\alpha \to 0$ a.e. I just realized that I made a mistake: it should be that $\alpha |u_\alpha|^2_{L^2}$ bounded indept of $\alpha$, which might not be able to get $\alpha u_\alpha$ convergent weakly in $L^2(\partial U)$. I don't have an idea passing to the limit at the boundary yet.